# Skip initializer if not rails s running it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got some code in an initializer and I'd like it to run only when the server starts but not when the console is started. Is there any way of telling them apart?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have special helper for this task

```
#lib/initializer_helpers.rb
module InitializerHelpers

  def self.skip_console_rake_generators &block
    skip(defined?(Rails::Console) || defined?(Rails::Generators) || File.basename($0) == "rake", &block)
  end

  def self.skip_rake_generators &block
    skip(defined?(Rails::Generators) || File.basename($0) == "rake", &block)
  end

  def self.skip_generators &block
    skip(defined?(Rails::Generators), &block)
  end

  def self.skip_console &block
    skip(defined?(Rails::Console), &block)
  end

  private

  def self.skip(condition, &block)
    raise ArgumentError.new("no block given") if block.blank?
    unless condition
      yield
    end
  end

end

# use it
InitializerHelpers.skip_console do
  # not executed in console
end
```

Update: extracted this idea to gem https://github.com/olegantonyan/initializer_helpers

Comment: This is helpful, but worth nothing that if you are using Spring, when executing `rails console` `defined?(Rails::Console)` will return `false` during the intializers (it seems to become `true` again after the initializers run)

Answer (score 9):

if you just need to check if the server is running you can use this one

```
if defined?(Rails::Server)
  # do something usefull
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if the Rails Console is defined:

```
run_code unless defined?(Rails::Console)
```